# highlight clicked and dim the rest plotly

Tags: r, plotly

How can I make plotly to highlight the line for the clicked legend and dim the rest? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732973/plotly-highlight-dim-rather-than-filter-when-clicking-on-point-in-legend#) is relevant but it focuses on diming the clicked.

```
library(plotly)
data(iris)
plot_ly(
 x     = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, 
 color = ~Species,
 data  = iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `itemclick` argument to `toggleothers` may dim everything than the chosen legend.

```
plot_ly(x  = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width, 
  color = ~Species,
  data  = iris) %>%
  layout(legend = list(itemclick = "toggleothers"))
```